# ParserError: Expected ',' but got 'memory'

Tags: solidity, smart-contract-wallets

```
event studentAdded(string memory _studentFirstName, string memory _studentLastName, uint256 _studentId);
```

from solidity:

```
ParserError: Expected ',' but got 'memory'
  --> contracts/4.Scorecard.sol:35:31:
   |
35 |     event studentAdded(string memory _studentFirstName, string memory _studentLastName, uint256 _studentId);
```

Comment: Can you share a compilable source code? It is likely that you are trying to compile a more recent version solidity code with an older compiler.

Comment: take out the memory keyword. not needed.
events normally start with a capital letter by convention e.g. StudentAdded

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should remove memory from the arguments, this should work:

```
event studentAdded(string _studentFirstName, string _studentLastName, uint256 _studentId);
```

Comment: Hi. You could improve your answer by explaining why doing this solve the problem.